# Pattern not applying on line object fabricjs

Tags: fabricjs

I am facing as issue using fabricjs as pattern is not applying on line object. It fills the object property with pattern images but is not showing pattern on line. jsfiddle ins attached.

```
var line = new fabric.Line([10, 25, 300, 25], {
    stroke: 'red',
    strokeWidth: 5,
    selectable: true,
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});
canvas.add(line);

fabric.util.loadImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/escheresque_ste.png', function (img) {
    line.setPatternFill({
        source: img,
        repeat: 'repeat'
    });
    canvas.renderAll();
});
console.log(line);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because Fabric js `setPatternFill` only apply pattern to the fill property of object.But line object not have a fill property,only have a `stroke` so we apply pattern differently like `new fabric.Pattern`

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas("c")
var line = new fabric.Line([10, 25, 300, 25], {
    stroke: 'red',
    fill:"red",
    strokeWidth: 10,
    selectable: true,
    left: 0,
    top: 0
});
canvas.add(line);

fabric.util.loadImage('http://fabricjs.com/assets/escheresque_ste.png', function (img) {
   
    line.stroke = new fabric.Pattern({
        source: img,
        repeat: 'repeat'
      });
      canvas.renderAll();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.min.js"></script>

<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks alot sharma.. its really halpful

Comment: Thanks for this nice snippet. `fabric.util.loadImage` solved my problem, too. + 1